# having issuse with objectid findbyid

Tags: mongodb, google-app-engine

```
app.get("/campgrounds/:id", function(req, res){
   campground.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundcampgroud){
       if (err){
         console.log(err);
       }else
          res.render("show", {campground: foundcampgroud});
     });
  });

 <a href="/campground/<%=  campground._id  %>" class="btn btn-primary">More info</a>
```

This is from my `ejs` file when i click more info i get Cannot `GET /campground/5d4e64ee738ee0001706d54b` in browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your API Endpoint, you mentioned `"/campgrounds/:id"`.
While in your href, you are mentioning `href="/campground/`

Try with `<a href="/campgrounds/<%=  campground._id  %>" class="btn btn-primary">More info</a>`

Comment: <a href="/campgrounds/<%=  campground._id  %>" class="btn btn-primary">More info</a> i am using this in my ejs file not working

Comment: Cannot GET /campground/5d4e64ee738ee0001706d54b

Comment: 2019-08-10T08:33:53.083879+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/campgrounds" host=infinite-brook-72873.herokuapp.com request_id=4399b862-3546-445e-860c-49f80d7dafe9 fwd="203.175.77.156" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=36ms status=200 bytes=2178 protocol=https
2019-08-10T08:34:05.402270+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/campground/5d4e64ee738ee0001706d54b" host=infinite-brook-72873.herokuapp.com request_id=206f7d86-c514-424f-949e-8599c8e6f208 fwd="203.175.77.156" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=418 protocol=https

Comment: i visited your web app hosted on heroku. `http://infinite-brook-72873.herokuapp.com/campground/5d4e64ee738ee0001706d54b` This is what shown in your browser. As you can see your browser is still pointing to `campground` not `campgrounds`. Either change it in you href or change Api Call end point. `app.get("/campground/:id"`  and then re-deploy on heroku with saved changes

Comment: Furthermore, if you visit this `http://infinite-brook-72873.herokuapp.com/campgrounds/5d4e64ee738ee0001706d54b`, you will get record. just replaced `campground` with `campgrounds` in URL. So issue is clearly related with your call.